# Equivalent in php of Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains

Tags: c#, php

```
Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains
```

What is the PHP equivalent of the above code in C#?

My code in C#:

```
              if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("X-MXit-LOGIN"))
                {

                    MxitId = Request.Headers["X-MXit-LOGIN"];
                }
                else
                {
                    MxitId = "Anonymous";
                }
```

PHP CODE:

```
 $login=NULL;
 if (isset($_SERVER["X-MXit-LOGIN"]) && !empty($_SERVER["X-MXit-LOGIN"])) {
 {
  $login = $_SERVER["X-MXit-LOGIN"];
 }
 else
{
 $login = 'abc';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HTTP_*` keys of `$_SERVER` where `-` is converted to `_` in all caps

```
$login = (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_MXIT_LOGIN"]) and $_SERVER["HTTP_X_MXIT_LOGIN"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_X_MXIT_LOGIN"] : "abc";
```